# Mouse hand cursor disappears in Google Chrome if page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using a normal

```
.foo {cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;width:250px;height:250px;background:#aaa;}
```

and

```
<div class="foo"><!--ph--></div>
```

as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/UZq5d/2/

If I hold the cursor over the gray background then reload the pages, the cursor defaults back to the arrow.

Is there any nifty and **lightweight** way to check if the cursor is over the .foo element on load? Or perhaps periodically, on mouse move? jQuery allowed.

EDIT: I'm seeing this behaviour using Chrome on OS X.

Comment: It probably also depends on the browser you're using... With Firefox 7, the cursor switches back to the pointer after the reload.

Comment: I don't seem to see that behaviour in IE8, what browser are you seeing this in? also, why are you defining the same property twice in the same css class?

Comment: in chrome when reloading the page its a pointer upon reload - but moving out and back into the div switched back to hand ....

Comment: `cursor:pointer;` is pointless in the CSS declaration

Comment: Yes, I was checking it in Chrome (14.0.835...).

Comment: @ManseUK Yeah that's what I meant. I don't want to move out of the div again.

Comment: @Mattis im using Chrome on OSX too (14.0.835.202)

Comment: cursor:hand is only needed for really old browsers (ie 5.5 and below). Is support for it that important? Would dropping the cursor:hand part (leaving only cursor:pointer) work consistently? (not reverting back to arrow on reload)

Comment: @GregPettit No that does not change anything.

Comment: I wonder why would you need this in the first place

Comment: @Mattis I found the problem in Chrome on Mac, When i change tab keeping cursor on same place, it is set to default cursor

Comment: I don't seem to encounter this problem using Google Chrome v19.

Comment: I see this all the time in Chrome/OSX too. Probably a bug, sometimes the cursor disappears completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just added the bounty and when I try it again it works in Chrome.

So, **currently working in Google Chrome version 18.0.1025.168 m**.

I'll close this question with this.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery to set the cursor initially works - ie without the css for cursor - see here to see what i mean --> http://jsfiddle.net/UZq5d/15/

Comment: its not 100% though - if i move the mouse around while the page is loading it doesn't seem to work correctly ... strange one that !!!

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. I'm not sure how to fix this without constantly checking where the mouse is.

Comment: Moving the mouse over an element with 'cursor:pointer;' in the CSS will change the cursor (even while the page loads). So just combine the jQuery and the CSS and you'll have all your bases covered.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.foo {cursor:pointer !important;cursor:hand;width:250px;height:250px;background:#aaa;}
```

Comment: `!important` only overwrites inline styles, adding it wont help here.

Answer (score 0):

Its working in this version as well.. 14.0.835.186 m

but actually, its taking sometime (1 or 2 seconds) to retain the hand cursor from I cursor...